# R, paste multiline text group

Tags: r, paste

I have a data as below

```
> cat(interim)    
                    name:Huff,
                    data: [[15,0,15],#FF0000]
                },{ 

                    name:santosh,
                    data: [[5,0,5],#FF0000]
                },{
> cat(lastline)  

                    name:sekhar,
                    data: [[7,0,7],0000CC]
```

and the final output that I'd like to have is as below.

```
                    name:Huff,
                    data: [[15,0,15],#FF0000]
                },{ 

                    name:santosh,
                    data: [[5,0,5],#FF0000]
                },{

                    name:sekhar,
                    data: [[7,0,7],0000CC]
```

I tried

```
paste( interim, lastline)
paste( interim, lastline, sep ="\n")
paste( interim, lastline, collapse = "\n")
paste( interim, lastline, sep ="\n", collapse = "\n")
```

but none of these work.

I was wondering it's due to the sequence that I used to generate the data.

(FYI, here's how I got interim dataset and lastline dataset.)

```
JV <- data.frame('poster'= c('Huff','santosh', 'sekhar', 'sekhar'), 
              'nb' = c(15,5,7,7), 
             'sum' = c(0,0,0,0), 
           'color' = c('#FF0000','#FF0000','0000CC','0000CC'))

a <- paste("                    name:", JV$poster[1:2], "," ,sep="")
b <- paste("                    data: [[",JV$nb[1:2], "," , JV$sum[1:2], "," , JV$nb[1:2]*(JV$sum[1:2]+1) , "]", ",", JV$color[1:2],"]",sep="")
c <- "                },{"
interim <- paste("\n",a,b,c,sep = "\n")

A <- paste("                    name:", JV$poster[4], "," ,sep="")
B <- paste("                    data: [[",JV$nb[4], "," , JV$sum[4], "," , JV$nb[4]*(JV$sum[4]+1) , "]", ",", JV$color[4],"]",sep="")
lastline <- paste("\n", A,B,sep = "\n")
```

Any advice will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've got a problem:

```
> interim <- "                    name:Huff,
+                     data: [[15,0,15],#FF0000]
+                 },{ 
+ 
+                     name:santosh,
+                     data: [[5,0,5],#FF0000]
+                 },{
+ "
> lastline <- "                    name:Huff,
+                     data: [[15,0,15],#FF0000]
+                 },{ 
+ 
+                     name:santosh,
+                     data: [[5,0,5],#FF0000]
+                 },{
+ 
+                     name:sekhar,
+                     data: [[7,0,7],0000CC]
+ "
> result<-paste(interim, lastline) 
> cat(result)
                name:Huff,
                data: [[15,0,15],#FF0000]
            },{ 

                name:santosh,
                data: [[5,0,5],#FF0000]
            },{
                 name:Huff,
                data: [[15,0,15],#FF0000]
            },{ 

                name:santosh,
                data: [[5,0,5],#FF0000]
            },{

                name:sekhar,
                data: [[7,0,7],0000CC]
```

I know it looks weird when you just ask R to display it in the prompt, but when you use it, it will expand the \n to the appropriate characters.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point. I added reproducible dataset. can you walk me through?